# Handling dependent react queries

Tags: javascript, react-query

I have two react queries in the same component

```
const { data: sdrData, status: sdrDataLoading } = useQuery(
    [queryInfo[0]?.dcsSysId, data[0]?.dcsStructSysId, data[cardIndex]?.dcsStructNodeId],
    () => getSDR(queryInfo[0]?.dcsSysId, data[0]?.dcsStructSysId, data[cardIndex]?.dcsStructNodeId),
  );



  const { isIdle, data: sdrTemplateData, status: sdrTemplateDataLoading } = useQuery(
    [sdrData[0]?.dcsSdrSysId, queryInfo[0]?.fldTemplateSysId],
    () =>
      SDRTemplateValues(sdrData[0]?.dcsSdrSysId, queryInfo[0]?.fldTemplateSysId, {
        // The query will not execute until the userId exists
        enabled: !!sdrData[0]?.dcsSdrSysId,
        retry: true,
      }),
  );
```

My second query is depended on the first I need to access `sdrData[0]` for the first arg in my query however when I do this the query is undefined initially and it fails. Is there a good way to handle this. I saw you can set it equal to a variable, but I'm still faced with the same problem.

I need a way to tell the first query to wait until the second query is finished before it tried to access the arguments. I thought you could set `enabled` like I did, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the data parameter I need to the beginning of the argument array like this.

```
const { data: sdrData, status: sdrDataLoading } = useQuery(
    queryInfo[0]?.dcsSysId && [
      queryInfo[0]?.dcsSysId,
      data[0]?.dcsStructSysId,
      data[cardIndex]?.dcsStructNodeId,
    ],
    () => getSDR(queryInfo[0]?.dcsSysId, data[0]?.dcsStructSysId, data[cardIndex]?.dcsStructNodeId),
  );

  const { data: sdrTemplateData, status: sdrTemplateDataLoading } = useQuery(
    sdrData?.[0]?.dcsSdrSysId && [sdrData?.[0]?.dcsSdrSysId, queryInfo[0]?.fldTemplateSysId],
    () => SDRTemplateValues(sdrData?.[0]?.dcsSdrSysId, queryInfo[0]?.fldTemplateSysId),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path here.

You just need to check if `sdrData` is undefined. You are trying to access the first element (`sdrData[0]`) but initially it's undefined.

```
...
{
  enabled: !!(sdrData && sdrData[0]?.dcsSdrSysId
}
...
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is still calling the query before the variables are defined.

Comment: could you re-create this in a codesandbox please?